# Javascript. Escape 'form' tag in concat

Tags: javascript

I want to add variable into my js code

```
var x = 1;
$(phrases).append('<form:input path="bla + ' x ' + bla" ...);
```

but I am getting:

> NumberFormatException: For input string: "+x+"

If I am using just input  it is working

```
var x = 1;
$(phrases).append('<input path="bla + ' x ' + bla" ...);
```

Why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<form:input>` is server-side Spring code. You can't generate it using client side JavaScript. It is too late for that, the code has already left the server.

You need to work with the HTML DOM, not Spring.